# How can I access my command line args from all my class?

Tags: c#, command-line, app-config

How can I pass a command line option to another class?

I have a program.cs that have arguments

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // One of args element is an output folder path
    }
```

I'm actually using CommandLine Parser

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
            .MapResult((opts) => RunOptions(opts), // in case parser sucess
            errs => HandleParseError(errs)); // in  case parser fail
    }
```

With an option folder like this

```
internal class Options
{
    [Option('o', "output", Required = true, HelpText = "Output folder where to save the report.")]
    public string OutputFolder { get; set; }
}
```

You can see I force the user to give me an output folder. for those that don't know how Command Line Parser is working just consider I can save one of the arguments in an `OutputFolder` property of an `Option` object.

I want to be sure I can access my args or my Option.OutputFolder property from everywhere in my program. I don't want to have to pass my Option or args in all my methods.

What should I do?

In fact I would like to be able to access my arguments a little bit like I can access my variables in my app.config file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RunOptions` would need to thread the `opts` variable to all the methods through parameters, or it can set a static property/field which other things can read. Up to the design of your application and your preferences.

There's nothing built-in to the CommandLineParser library to access the parsed data statically, so you need to maintain the data connection yourself.